# Upgrade from AutoMapper 7.0.1 to 11.0.1 how to handle `ForAllOtherMembers`

Tags: automapper, .net-6.0

I'm trying to migrate an existing .NET Framework 4.8 WebApi project to .NET 6.0.

I have installed the latest version of AutoMapper by running the following command in PMC:
`Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 11.0.1`

I have replaced all occurrences in the mapping profile that call either `ResolveUsing` or `UseValue` which have been deprecated with their new equivalent `MapFrom`.

However, I have a few usages of `ForAllOtherMembers` which is also deprecated and I'm struggling to work out what to replace it with as there doesn't seem to be a new equivalent.

Effectively what the existing code was trying to achieve was to conditionally choose whether to create a mapping for any remaining members **that have not been previously configured** based on whether the source member has either an `internal` or `private` setter or not.

The compiler error is occurring in the last line of the `CreateCycleMaps` method in the **Minimal code snippet for new .NET 6.0 code version**.

Anyone know if this is still possible to achieve and if so how?

Thanks.

**Minimal code snippet for existing .NET Framework 4.8 version**

```
/// <summary>
/// AutoMapper config.
/// </summary>
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create maps.
    /// </summary>
    public static void CreateMaps()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            CreateCycleMaps(cfg);
        });
    }

    private static void CreateCycleMaps(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<CycleRequestModel, Cycle>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Variables, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.CycleCollectionSplitType, o =>
            {
                o.Condition(cm => cm.CollectionSplitType.HasValue);
                o.MapFrom(cm => cm.CollectionSplitType);
            })
            .ForMember(c => c.CycleStepErrorAction, o =>
            {
                o.Condition(cm => cm.StepErrorAction.HasValue);
                o.MapFrom(cm => cm.StepErrorAction);
            })
            .ForAllOtherMembers(IgnoreSourceValuesWithInternalOrPrivateSetters);
    }

    private static void IgnoreSourceValuesWithInternalOrPrivateSetters<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> member)
    {
        member.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember, destMember) =>
        {
            if (sourceMember == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var sourceProp = source.GetType().GetProperty(member.DestinationMember.Name);
            return sourceProp?.GetSetMethod(false) != null;
        });
    }
}
```

**Minimal code snippet for new .NET 6.0 code version**

```
/// <summary>
/// AutoMapper config.
/// </summary>
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateCycleMaps();
    }

    private void CreateCycleMaps()
    {
        CreateMap<CycleRequestModel, Cycle>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Variables, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(c => c.CycleCollectionSplitType, o =>
            {
                o.Condition(cm => cm.CollectionSplitType.HasValue);
                o.MapFrom(cm => cm.CollectionSplitType);
            })
            .ForMember(c => c.CycleStepErrorAction, o =>
            {
                o.Condition(cm => cm.StepErrorAction.HasValue);
                o.MapFrom(cm => cm.StepErrorAction);
            })
            .ForAllOtherMembers(IgnoreSourceValuesWithInternalOrPrivateSetters);
    }

    private static void IgnoreSourceValuesWithInternalOrPrivateSetters<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> member)
    {
        member.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember, destMember) =>
        {
            if (sourceMember == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var sourceProp = source?.GetType()?.GetProperty(member.DestinationMember.Name);
            return sourceProp?.GetSetMethod(false) != null;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a custom type converter for that type.

Comment: This works for me "CreateMap<TSource, TDest>(MemberList.None)" with Automapper 11 and .Net  6.0

Comment: Not sure that will work for my scenario?

I want to be able to explicitly configure 3 or 4 src to dest mappings with custom conditions, then I want to map the remaining source members not already configured, but I only want to map those remaining source members if they don't have a private or internal property setter.

Answer (score 2):

I converted my Automapper Profile like below and it works for me with Automapper 11 and .Net 6.0. Click [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) for the official Automapper 11 guide.

```
CreateMap<TSource, TDest>(MemberList.None);
```

Comment: Not sure that will work for my scenario? I want to be able to explicitly configure 3 or 4 src to dest mappings with custom conditions, then I want to map the remaining source members not already configured, but I only want to map those remaining source members if they don't have a private or internal property setter.

Comment: So what does this actually do? The release notes say of `ForAllOtherMembers()` that `That was used to disable mapping by convention, not something we want to support.`. So is that not exactly what `MemberList.None` is doing?